# nose tests of Pylons app with models in init_model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons, nose, nosetests

I have a stock Pylons app created using `paster create -t pylons` with one controller and matched functional test, added using `paster controller`, and a SQLAlchemy table and mapped ORM class. The SQLAlchemy stuff is defined in the `init_model()` function rather than in module scope (and needs to be there).

Running `python setup.py test` raises an exception because `nose` is somehow causing `init_model()` to be called twice within the same process, so it's trying to create a model that already exists.

I can hackishly fix this by setting and checking a global variable inside `init_model()`, but (a) I'd rather not, and (b) third-party libraries such as AuthKit that dynamically define models break the tests as well, and can't be so easily changed.

Is there a way to fix `nose` tests for Pylons, or should I write my own test script and just use `unittest`, `loadapp`, and `webtest` directly? Any working examples of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try debugging your nosetest run. Why not put:

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

in the `init_model()` function and see how it is getting invoked more than once.

With PDB running you can see the stack trace using the `where` command:

```
w(here)
Print a stack trace, with the most recent frame at the bottom.
An arrow indicates the "current frame", which determines the
context of most commands.  'bt' is an alias for this command.
```

Comment: Using pdb showed that the stock tests/__init__.py provided by paster was first running the setup-app command, then actually running the tests, and this accounts for init_model being called twice. I commented out the setup-app line, and everything works fine. I guess the remaining question is why paster puts that in there when it doesn't seem necessary and doesn't work out-of-the-box.

Comment: jasonjs: my understanding/guess is that \_\_init\_\_.py is trying to create the database tables for you so you wouldn't need to run paster setup-app test.ini manually before you can run the tests.